# Scrape Facebook public event pages

Tags: facebook, scraping

I need to web scrape facebook for some data.

I only need to visit 50 facebook pages every like 1 hour. I will be visting pages of events.

I need to scrape the event name, the event time, and the event location. I will be scraping public pages.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! And what are you looking for? A binary for Solaris? A library for Modula2? What is your price limit? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. We can only give good recommendations when we know what exactly you're looking for ;) Thanks!